# firefox css bug/issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, select

While working fine Chrome and IE7-9, firefox brings yet another surprise...

http://jsfiddle.net/D3zXj/

What I'm trying to do is to change the color of `Select` according to the color of the selected `option`. For some mysterious reason it doesn't work in firefox.

Any ideas why?

```
$('#selectstat_sch').change(function(){
    $(this).css('color',$('option:selected',this).css('color'));
}).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on the undefined, we may want to validate first our css property,

This should also work if some other properties are present.

http://jsfiddle.net/D3zXj/2/

```
    var style=$('option:selected',this).attr('style');
    var matches=style.match(/color:([^;]+)/);
    if (matches) $(this).css('color',matches[1]);
    //else alert('no match');
```

Comment: Yes, this is better technique.

Answer (score 0):

Use the attr('style') instead css('color'):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectstat_sch').change(function(){
        $(this).attr('style',$('option:selected').attr('style'));
    });
});
```

but this copy and overwrites the whole styles.

Comment: Hehe, thanks, that's a simple and yet neat. Might as well suit for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

When the option is selected, it gets a different computed color than the one in your HTML, because there's a UA sheet rule that styles selected options.  You can see this, in fact: the selected option is white with a blue background.

So instead of getting the computed color from the option, you may want to just get `.style.color`, since that's what you want,